# How to assign correct serial No. no in paged GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

If I write the below code, the gridview shows the content but the serial no (S.N.) starts from 1 again in the second page.

The data is called through Custom Component(.DLL).

How to solve this?

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
  GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  MMSLAYER.BLL.ReportBLL rb = new ReportBLL();
  dt = rb.atmservicing(Convert.ToInt32(ddlServiceBy.SelectedValue), 
  Convert.ToDateTime(txtDateFrom.Text), Convert.ToDateTime(txtDateTo.Text));
  GridView1.DataSource = dt;
  GridView1.DataBind();
  GridView1.Visible = true;
  ViewState["dtList"] = dt;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me as if you are printing (S.N) with the help of following code:

```
 e.Row.RowIndex
```

Instead of this, try the following line of code:

```
e.Row.DataItemIndex
```

Ofcourse, this should be in your gridview row-databound event.

Comment: No, I have inserted extra code as 

`    <Columns>     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Serial No" >
   <ItemTemplate>    
       <%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex + 1%>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>`

for my S.N. Column.

Comment: Exactly that's the problem. You should try to use dataitemindex instead of rowindex.

Answer (score 0):

In Source view, set the AllowPaging attribute of the  element to true, as in the following example:

```
 <asp:GridView Runat="server" ID="GridView1" AllowPaging="true" />
```

You can set the size of your page to specify how many rows are displayed at once. In addition, you can set the style of the links used to create navigation buttons. You can choose from the following types:

```
Next and previous buttons. The button captions can be any text you want.

Page numbers, which allow users to jump to a specific page. You can specify how many numbers are displayed; if there are more pages, an ellipsis (...) is displayed next to the numbers.
```

To change the number of rows displayed per page

```
Select the GridView control, and in the Properties window, set PageSize to the number of rows you want to display per page.
```

To specify default paging with Next and Previous buttons

```
Set the GridView control to allow paging.

In the Properties window, expand the PagerSettings node.

Set Mode to NextPrevious.
```

Answer (score 0):

Add OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" inside your GridView declaration:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" ....>
```

Add TemplateField inside your GridView:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Serial number">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblSerial" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Add this in .cs file

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Label lblSerial = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblSerial");
            lblSerial.Text = ((GridView1.PageIndex * GridView1.PageSize) + e.Row.RowIndex + 1).ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the follownig with the template field:

```
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
             <%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me as if you are printing (S.N) with the help of following code:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblslno" Text='<%# Container.DisplayIndex + 1 %>' runat="server"/>
```

Instead of this, try the following line of code:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblslno" Text='<%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>‘ runat="server"/>
```

> Note the use of `DataItemIndex` instead of `DisplayIndex`.

Comment: It seems to me as if you are printing (S.N) with the help of following code:
<asp:Label ID="lblslno" Text='<%# Container.DisplayIndex + 1 %>' runat="server"/>

Instead of this, try the following line of code:
<asp:Label ID="lblslno" Text='<%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>' runat="server"/>

Comment: Hello, and welcome. You can edit your original answer using the little gray “Edit” button in order to fix the code samples. That way, people won’t need to read your comments to understand the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me as if you are printing (S.N) with the help of following code:

' runat="server"/>--%>

Instead of this, try the following line of code:

' runat="server"/>--%>